# What is the level displayed as "Default" in a apiblueprint document?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

When i create a new api documentation in apiary.io, the rendered document and navigation shows structural level which are not visible in the editor:

- INTRODUCTION
- REFERENCE

  - Default

[image: Navigation levels]

While I can accept the highest levels to generated magically, I would like to rename and duplicate the second level.

How do I do it? How is it called? It has CSS classes *resourceGroupName* but this does not appear to be the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I have overseen that some words that look like normal text are in fact keywords for the apiblueprint parser. One of them is Group, explained here: https://docs.apiary.io/api_101/api_blueprint_tutorial/#resource-groups